как добавить метку на карте?
с переходом на апи 3 все в разы усложнилось, документация сырая, толком мало что понятно, пытался разобрать по этому примеру - https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/examples/cases/create-default-marker
но ничего не вышло
хотел сделать что то на подобии такой метки, скорее всего придется также задействовать css, чтобы стилизовать данную метку, но мне бы хотя бы понять, как ее вообще создать

вот изначальный код
export const initMap = async () => {
  await ymaps3.ready;

  const { YMap, YMapDefaultSchemeLayer, YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer, YMapDefaultMarker } = ymaps3;

  // Инициализация карты
  const map = new YMap(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoomRange: { min: 2, max: 15 }, // Допустимые уровни масштабирования
    location: {
      center: [100, 0], // Центр карты
      zoom: 2, // Масштаб по умолчанию
    },
  });

  // Добавляем стандартный слой схемы карты
  map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer());

  // Создание метки
  const myPlacemark = new YMapDefaultMarker({
    coordinates: [-23.70013292614432, 133.80887486560016], // Координаты метки (Австралия)
    properties: {
      iconContent: 'Австралия', // Текст на метке
      balloonContent: 'Это Австралия!' // Текст в балуне (всплывающем окне)
    },
    style: {
      icon: {
        preset: 'islands#blueStretchyIcon', // Тип иконки
      },
    },
  });

  // Добавляем метку на карту
  map.addChild(myPlacemark);

};


Вы правы, формат меток несколько изменился. Потому и список доступных параметров для дефолтных меток тоже другой. Вот базовый вариант добавления метки:
// Добавляем слой объектов
map.addChild(new YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer())

// Подключение модуля меток
  const {YMapDefaultMarker} = (await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-markers@0.0.1'));

// Создание метки
const myPlacemark = new YMapDefaultMarker({
  "coordinates": [135.5,-25.5],
  "color": "red",
  "title": "Австралия",
  "subtitle": "Это Австралия"
});

// Добавление метки на карту
map.addChild(myPlacemark);


Спасибо за предоставленный код, но если я допустим хочу свою svg иконку добавить, а не использовать стандартную иконку яндекс, то как будет выглядеть код?
ну и второй вопрос, если я захочу добавить сразу несколько меток, как это реализовать

также не смог найти, как поменять расположение окошки с текстом (title, subtitile), хотел их расположить изначально над иконкой, т.е сверху

Это стандартная метка. Она не подразумевает кастомизации. Реализован пакетом ymaps3-markers, ссылка на документацию которого есть в разделе о пакетах справки https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/ref/packages/
